# .Net core 3.1 application deploy on windows 7

Tags: wpf, .net-core, windows-7, wix, wix3.5

Guys I have a solution containing projects of Api, class libraries and a WPF app.
All of targets are **.Net Core** 3.1.

I used **Wix** tools to create a **self-contained** installer.
It works well on windows 10 (well, it should) but i need an installation on windows 7.
But after installation the app doesn't start and there is no errors.

1- Is there any **specific** configuration for old windows 7?
2- **if yes**  Which configurations should i check for existing projects?

Comment: Have you tried taking WiX out of the troubleshooting variables and just manually deploy to Win7? I'm just throwing out a WAG here but I'm thinking that the .Net 3.1 deployment on Win7 may be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is there any specific configuration for old windows 7?*

Yes, there is, according to https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.1/3.1-supported-os.md#windows, you must have SP1 installed, and according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=netcore31, you need additional dependencies (KB2533623 update).

Obs. I had a similar problem in my test environment, and installing SP1 + KB2533623 solved the problem.

Regards.

Comment: Hi just wondering does it require the machine to restart after installing SP1?

Comment: I can't download KB2533623 - "We're sorry, this download is no longer available."

Answer (score -1):

For me, installing sdk on windows 7 solved the issue https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1